# Current Touch location

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

How does one get the current touch location from a GestureRecognizer?

I need to get the current touch location when the touch has begun as well as when the touch has ended.

What property is used to get this location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gesture recognizer handler:

```
 CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
```

you could specify a different view, if you need it.